# A Sub-group of affine group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

I need some help and fresh perspectives concerning an exercise on a subgroup of affine group.

> Let $A = \{x\mapsto ax+b \ | \ (a,b)\in \mathbb R^*\times \mathbb R \}$.
>
> $1)$ Show that $A$ is a subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}(\mathbb R)$ isomorphic to
> $$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
> a&b\\
> 0&1\\ 
> \end{pmatrix} \in GL_2(\mathbb R) \mid (a,b)\in \mathbb R^*\times \mathbb R \right\} $$
>
> $2)$ Let $G$ be a subgroup of $A$ such that every element of $G$ has an fixed point. Show that this fixed point is the same for every element of $G$ (excluding $x\mapsto x$).
>
> $3)$ Show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(\mathbb R^*, \times)$. Derive a characterisation of the subgroups of $A$ which have the same property as $G$.

The first question isn't difficult. The exercise starts to become difficult with the second question.

Here is my proof :
Let $f,g\in G$ (not the identity) such that they have different fixed points.
Let $f(x) = ax+b$ and $g(x)=cx+d$. It cannot be the case $a,c=1$; otherwise, we would have $f(x)=x+b$ with $b\neq 0$ and no fixed point would exist.
Because they don't have the same fixed points, we have:
$$\frac{b}{1-a}\neq \frac{d}{1-c} \Leftrightarrow \frac{b}{ac} - \frac{b}{a} \neq \frac{d}{ac} - \frac{d}{c}$$
Now let's compute $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}) \circ (f\circ g)(x)$:

- $(f\circ g)(x) = acx + ad +b$
- $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(x) = \frac{1}{ac}x - \frac{d}{ac} - \frac{b}{a}$
- $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}) \circ (f\circ g)(x) = x + \frac{d}{c}+ \frac{b}{ac} - \frac{d}{ac} - \frac{b}{a} $

In view of the fact that $\frac{b}{1-a}\neq \frac{d}{1-c} \Leftrightarrow \frac{b}{ac} - \frac{b}{a} \neq \frac{d}{ac} - \frac{d}{c}$, we see that $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}) \circ (f\circ g)$ does not have a fixed point $-$ which is impossible because it is in $G$.
So $f,g$ must have the same fixed points.

I want to know if there is a better proof, maybe using the isomorphism from $1)$.

I have some difficulties with $3)$. First of all, using the determinant map as a morphism between $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathbb R^*$, we find that $G$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $(\mathbb R^*, \times)$. (We just have to compose.) But after that, I don't know how to derive a characterisation.

I want to know how can we deduce something about $G$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that the action of $A$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is $2$-transitive, so for (2), by conjugation you can assume that the two fixed points are say $0$ and $1$. This should at least simplify the algebra.

Comment: For $3$, just using ($1$-)transitivity, you can assume that the common fixed point is $0$, but the stabilizer of $0$ is exactly $\mathbb{R}^\times$ acting by $a \cdot x = ax$.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if you know that $A$ is a semidirect product $A=\mathbb{R}\rtimes\mathbb{R}^*$. And $G$ is just a subgroup of section $\mathbb{R}^*\hookrightarrow A$ which can be identified with a conjugate group of $0\rtimes\mathbb{R}^*$ or its subgroup. So $G$ can be seen as $\{\begin{bmatrix} a&-ab_0+b_0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}|a\in K\}$ where $K$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$ and $b_0$ is a fixed real number.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, its is easier to solve first the third question. The map $F:G\to \bf R^*$ $f( ax+b)=a$ is an homomorphism. Its kernel is reduce to the identity, because $x\to x+b$ has no fixed point if $b\not =0$. Therefore $F$ is injective and $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\bf R^*$, in particular abelian. To prove that there exists a unique fixed point, choose some element $g_0\in G\setminus \{e\}$. It has a unique fixed point $x_0$. No we use the following : let $G$ be an ableian group operate on a set and $g_0\in G$. Then the set of fixed point of $g_0$ is invariant par $G$ : $ g_0 (g x)=g(g_0x)=gx$. As $x_0$ is the unique fixed point of $g$ it is stable par $G$, and it is fixed.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks, it is a great way to solve $2)$.

Answer (score 1):

For (2): If you use the isomorphism, remember that a fixpoint of a matrix $A$ is a vector $\mathbf{v}$ for which $A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}$. In particular, this shows that a matrix $A$ has a fixpoint vector if and only if it has an eigenvalue of $1$.

In your case you can ``vecotrify'' this question by finding a group isomorphism $\mathbb{R} \cong X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ where $X$ is the set
$$
X := \left\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} x \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \; : \; x \in \mathbb{R} \right\rbrace.
$$
Note that the translation here requires noting that the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to the action of your subgroup $A$ on $X$ through matrix multiplication, i.e., via
$$
gx \cong \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ax + b \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
for $g \in G$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus to find a fixpoint of $g$, your first goal should be to show that the corresponding matrix in $A$ has an eigenvalue of $1$ (which is a happy consequence of $A$ being comprised of upper triangular matrices). Now you just need to find your eigenvectors!

Comment: Thanks ! I like the way of just searching for eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure about my answer. So tell me if there is any problem.

Using this function as a morphism, we can find the subgroups of $(\mathbb R^*, \times)$ :
$$\phi : 
\begin{array}{crcl}
(\{-1,1\},\times)\times(\mathbb R, +) & \longrightarrow & (\mathbb R^*, \times)\\
(a,x) & \longmapsto & ae^{x} 
\end{array}$$

We know all subgroups of $(\{-1,1\},\times)\times(\mathbb R, +)$:

- $\{1\}\times a\mathbb Z$ with $a\in \mathbb R^+$
- $\{-1,1\}\times a\mathbb Z$ with $a\in \mathbb R^+$
- $\{1\}\times I$ with $\overline I = \mathbb R$
- $\{-1,1\}\times I$ with $\overline I = \mathbb R$

So with $\phi$, we get all the subgroups of $(\mathbb R^*, \times)$ :

- $\{a^k|k\in \mathbb Z\}$ with $a\in \mathbb R^+$
- $\{\varepsilon a^k|k\in \mathbb Z, \varepsilon\in \{-1,1\}\}$ with $a\in \mathbb R^+$
- $H$ a set such that : $\overline H = \mathbb R^+$ and $0\notin H$
- $J$ a set such that : $J = \{\varepsilon x| x\in H, \varepsilon\in \{-1,1\} \}$ where $\overline H = \mathbb R^+$ and $0\notin H$

Thanks to @Thomas, we have a morphism: $$F : 
\begin{array}{crcl}
(G,\circ) & \longrightarrow & (\mathbb R^*, \times)\\
(x\mapsto ax+b) & \longmapsto & a 
\end{array}$$

Let $d$ be the fixed point in $G$,
we have $4$ types of subgroups possible for $G$ :

- $\{x\mapsto a^k x+(1-a^k)d|k\in \mathbb Z\}$ with $a\in\mathbb R^+$
- $\{x\mapsto \varepsilon a^k x+(1-\varepsilon a^k)d|k\in \mathbb Z, \varepsilon \in \{-1,1\}\}$ with $a\in\mathbb R^+$
- $\{x\mapsto ax+(1-a)d|a\in H \}$ with $\overline H = \mathbb R^+$ and $0\notin H$
- $\{x\mapsto \varepsilon ax+(1- \varepsilon a)d|a\in H, \varepsilon \in \{-1,1\} \}$ with $\overline H = \mathbb R^+$ and $0\notin H$